# Property assignment expected when using template literals to create an Object

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to create an object inside a JSON object that will be later populated from FormData:

```js
function toJSONstring(form) {

  let object = {`"${form.name}": {}`}; //Property assignment expected.ts(1136)

  let formData = new FormData(form);
  formData.forEach((value, key) => {
    // Reflect.has in favor of: object.hasOwnProperty(key)
    if (!Reflect.has(object, key)) {
      object[key] = value;
      return;
    }
    if (!Array.isArray(object[key])) {
      object[key] = [object[key]];
    }
    object[key].push(value);
  });
  form.reset();
  return JSON.stringify(object);
}
```

**What I want to obtain is the following JSON:**

```json
{
    "network_settings": {
        "connection": "wifi",
        "type": "dhcp",
        "ssid": "Jorj_2.4",
        "ip_address": "",
        "gateway": "",
        "subnet": "",
        "dns": ""
    }
}
```

but I get `Property assignment expected.ts(1136)`.

If I replace

```
let object = {`"${form.name}": {}`};
```

with `let object = {};` then I get a normal JSON object:

```json
{
    "connection": "wifi",
    "type": "dhcp",
    "ssid": "Jorj_2.4",
    "ip_address": "",
    "gateway": "",
    "subnet": "",
    "dns": ""
}
```

How can I created the nested object that I want ?

Comment: We need to know what form contains

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff How can I do that ? The form has 100 lines in HTML. As I said in the question: using `let object = {};`  gets me the following JSON ```{
    "connection": "wifi",
    "type": "dhcp",
    "ssid": "Jorj_2.4",
    "ip_address": "",
    "gateway": "",
    "subnet": "",
    "dns": ""
}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go back to what you had first:

```
let object = {};
```

And after you have populated the object, wrap it using [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) syntax:

```
return JSON.stringify({ [form.name]: object });
```

Comment: Thank. Works like a charm. I've first tried **return JSON.stringify(object[`${form.name}`]);** but it did not work.

Answer (score 3):

For dynamic keys in script you have to enclose your expression inside `[]`

```js
const form = {
  name: 'network_settings'
}
let obj = {[form.name]: {}};
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: @trincot was faster. Thank you.